# Потоки. Очередь. Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу

Tags: c++

Ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00DE3D56 в thread.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x07565C09.

Исключение происходит внутри функции `this->queue.push(val);`

Файл xmemory:

```
template<class _Objty,
    class... _Types>
    static void construct(_Alloc&, _Objty * const _Ptr, _Types&&... _Args)
    {   // construct _Objty(_Types...) at _Ptr // Тут вылазит исключение
    ::new (const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const volatile void *>(_Ptr)))
        _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }
```

Код

```
#include <string>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

class BaseDumper 
{
public:
    BaseDumper();
    virtual ~BaseDumper();
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void Add(int val);
private:
    std::atomic_bool started;
    std::queue<int> queue;
    std::queue<int> swap_queue;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
    std::thread thread;
    std::mutex mutex;
};
BaseDumper::BaseDumper() :
    started(false)
{

}

BaseDumper::~BaseDumper()
{

}

void BaseDumper::Add(int val)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->mutex);
    this->queue.push(val);
    this->cond_var.notify_all();
}

void BaseDumper::Start()
{
    this->started = true;
    this->thread = std::thread([this]()
    {
        while (this->started)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
            while (this->queue.empty() && this->started)
            {
                this->cond_var.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
            }
            this->swap_queue.swap(this->queue);
            lock.unlock();
            while(!this->swap_queue.empty())
            {
                this->swap_queue.pop();
            }           
        }
    });
}

void BaseDumper::Stop()
{
    this->started = false;
    if (this->thread.joinable())
    {
        this->thread.join();
    }
}

void work(BaseDumper* dumper)
{
    int n = 10000;
    while (--n)
    {
        dumper->Add(n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BaseDumper* dumper = new BaseDumper;
    dumper->Start();

    std::thread thr([dumper]() { work(dumper); });
    thr.join();
    dumper->Stop();
    delete dumper;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема заключается в доступе к `this->queue` из разных потоков без синхронизации. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->mutex);` создает временную переменную, которая сразу же уничтожается и потому никакой синхронизации при вызове `queue.push` на следующей строке не происходит. Соответственно для исправления достаточно сделать тут обычную переменную.

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> const lock{this->mutex};
    this->queue.push(val);
}
this->cond_var.notify_all();
```